# Poissonic distribution

Tags: probability

I was asked this: the number of electrons coming out of a device during 1 hour is a random Poisson variable with $\lambda = 4$. Electrons coming out of the device hit a wall with a probability of $\frac{3}{4}$ independently. What is the probability that from the electrons that came out of the device during 1 hour:
1) at least 1 hit the wall?
2) exactly 3 hit the wall?

So at first I calculated the probability that at least 1 electron came out of the device during 1 hour and got $1 - \frac{1}{e^4}$ and then:

for (1), I said if $k$ is the number of electrons that came out during 1 hour then my answer is $(1 - \frac{1}{e^4}) \cdot {k \choose 1} \cdot \frac{3}{4}$ 
I took the probability that at least one electron came out and then chose 1 from the $k$ that came out  and then multiplied by the probability that they hit the wall.

for (2) I did a similar thing but I took the probability that at least 3 came out during 1 hour, then choose 3 from the $k$ electrons that came out, and then multiplied by $(3/4)^3\cdot(1/4)^{k-3}$

But I think I'm not even doing this right. Can I get some help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly need to use both CDF and PDF here:

@Mark provided the formula for you nicely so you should do it by hand.

Electrons coming out of the device hit a wall with a probability (p)
of $\frac{3}{4}$, thus the ***expected amount*** of electrons coming out of a device and hitting a wall is $4*\frac{3}{4}$ = $3$ **per hour**

Part A) at least one implies it could be 1,2,3,4,etc.

$$P (x\geq 1)=1-P (x=0)$$

Part B) exactly 3 implies

$$P (x=3)$$

Can you take it from here? You have all the given information in the problem.

Using R

Part A: Using the CDF for Poisson to calculate the "cumulative" probabilities

```
 1-ppois(0,3) = .95
```

Part B: Using the PDF for Poisson to calculate the density at a specific value

```
 dpois(3,3) = .224
```

Here is the density curve, along with x = 3 labeled. [image]

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If we randomly remove 3/4 of the electrons, then the Poisson with intensity 4 ($\lambda = 4$) becomes an other Poisson with intensity $\lambda' = 4 * 3 / 4 =3$. I.e. instead of 4 electrons arriving randomly and independently from our device, only 3 electrons reach the wall, still randomly and independently.

Now that we have a Poission with $\lambda' = 3$ can calculate question 1 and 2 using the probability mass function and the cumulative distribution function.

Hope this helps, let me know otherwise!

**EDIT**

By probability mass function I mean $\frac {\lambda ^{k}e^{-\lambda }}{k!}$. You might have learned this on an other name. It tells you what is the probability of exactly k hits. Using λ′=3 and k=3 you'll get the answer to 2).